# Is Ubuntu 13.10 compatible with Razor Nostromo or Logitech G13 for gaming?

Tags: games, logitech

Ok so I am interested to buy a Razor Nostromo or Logitech G13, but I don't know if Ubuntu 13.10 is offering some support for this devices.

In my case I don`t want to go back to Windows for one game as I am a Linux user.

I'm asking for your help, if I buy this device, can I still play my favourite game or not? 
Thanx and I will look forward for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how new your Nostromo is, I have been in contact with a developer who has made a tournament authorized programming tool w/gui for the n52 and n52te.

I have the n50 and n52 (the Belkin versions) which I consider better than the n52te.

Here is a link to his site. http://sourceforge.net/projects/kbmaster/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the g13 for ubuntu and most other linux desktops with this (rather old and non-maintained) driver http://code.google.com/p/linux-g13-driver/

Has no way to control the display, but it works for the most part.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.